# direction of object gets iterated over

Tags: python, pygame

I am doing a remake of doodle jump. The problem i have encountered is that the direction at which the object is facing gets iterated over. What I mean by this, is something like this:
If the direction is equal to 'right', but, you decided to change the direction further through the loop, so the direction should become 'left', but since the loop starts from the first line, it just almost immediately changes back to direction 'right'.

like so:
loop:
right
if something happens:
left

The problem is that the loop starts from line one, so it immediately makes it back to right

Here is the code:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.direction = -1
        player_img = pygame.image.load('player1.png')
        if self.direction == 1:
            self.player = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (100, 100))
        if self.direction == -1:
            player = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (100, 100))
            self.player = pygame.transform.flip(player, True, False)
        self.rect = self.player.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jumped = False

    def update(self):
        dx = 0
        dy = 0

        # Key windings
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            dx -= 5
            self.direction = -1
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            dx += 5
            self.direction = 1
```

Comment: create a variable outside the loop that will tell the direction, inside the loop change it based on condition else move to the direction

Comment: also everything in `__init__` will be executed once when initiating the class

Comment: move the `if direction == 1` and the other inside the update loop, also for that You can use `if/elif` to increase the performance so that only one statement gets checked and change them a bit too both to `self.` just name one image left and the other right with `self.` in front and swithc between those in the update loop, also use if/elif

Comment: @Matiiss I thought of that and it is a very good idea, but self wont get defined if its outside

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I would redefine Your class:

```py
class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.direction = -1
        self.player_img_left = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('player1.png'), (100, 100))
        self.player_img_right = pygame.image.flip(self.player_img_left, True, False)

        self.rect = self.player_img_left.get_rect()
        self.direction = 1
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jumped = False

    def update(self):
        dx = 0
        dy = 0

        # Key windings
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            dx -= 5
            self.direction = 1
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            dx += 5
            self.direction = -1
            
        if self.direction == -1:
            img = self.player_img_right
        elif self.direction == 1:
            img = self.player_img_left
```

and at the end You would want to blit `img` (also I may have messed up the left and right)